# Rails Search Self Referential Relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I am trying to allow users to search through their own friends by email address. I'd like to do something like:

```
current_user.search('test@fake.com')
```

and have it return an array of current users friends that have that email address.

So I have a very basic friendship relationship set up on my user model

```
user.rb
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, through: :friendships, source: :friend
has_many :inverse_friendships, class_name: 'Friendship', foreign_key: 'friend_id'
has_many :inverse_friends, through: :inverse_friendships, source: :user

friendship.rb
belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'friend_id'
belongs_to :user
```

I want to set up a method on my user model that can search through their friends by email address. It's not working so well

```
def search(query)
  conditions = ['friends.user_id = ? AND email LIKE ? ', self.id, "%#{query}%"]
  User.includes(:friends).where(conditions)
end
```

I guess I'm just not sure how to format my active record query / SQL here, since I am trying to search on the relations of a self referential model. Any one have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digital Cake is going in the right direction, but not exactly correct. A scope is a method of User, not user. What you need is:

```
def followers_by_email(email) 
   friends.where("email like ?", "%#{email}%")
end
```

This returns an ActiveRecord::Relation to which you can chain other conditions, order, paginate, etc as in

```
user.followers_by_email("me@example.com").order(:first_name).limit(10)
```

Comment: this totally works, and obviously it should. I tried this and must have had some type or something that I didn't notice because it worked flawlessly when i tried it again.

Answer (score 1):

Good time to use active record scopes. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Heres a simple example

user.rb

```
scope :followers, friends.where(:published => true).order("created_at DESC").limit(150)
```

in your controller

```
@followers = User.followers
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have some success with:

```
conditions = ['contacts.user_id = ? AND users.email LIKE ? ', self.id, "%#{query}%"]
User.includes(:inverse_friends).where(conditions)
```

Though it's strange that it works, I'm not entirely sure why it does.